# validating $_POST's contain with PHP. that must be number

Tags: php, post

I'd like to validate $_POST's contain, that must be number. How can i check out $_POST's contain with PHP?

for example (what i want as the result):

```
1876 //true
2.34 // false
erfka // false
1djs33 // false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ctype_digit](http://php.net/ctype_digit) is your friend. It checks that only digits are contained in the variable, not periods or anything other. ctype_digit doesn't even allow negative numbers, but **just digits**.

It actually also checks that there *is* a number contained. The empty string is evaluated to `false` with ctype_digit.

Comment: you solved my problem. i tested your way. it works. thank you. A+ help

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to use ctype_digit!

Answer (score 0):

Try using PHP [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) function

Comment: thanks for your answer. but is_numeric gives true as result for the 1djs33. i need to accept only numbers.

Comment: @strauberry What's the problem casting it after to integer?

Comment: This is actually the best answer, because it accepts integer **and** float values. In contrast to a type cast, this function doesn't accept numbers like 1djs33.

Comment: martin, it's not the best answer since it doesn't meet the specification (floats should not be allowed).

Comment: @Emil - Indeed your are right, i got it the other way round, sorry.

Comment: Robik, here's a bunch of other values where is_numeric returns `true` and ctype_digit returns `false`: "0XAE", "-2e-1", "-5"

Answer (score -1):

Try with this code -

```
if(strpos($_POST['number'],'.') === false && is_numeric($_POST['number']))
echo 'Its a numeriac int value';
else
echo 'not a numeric value';
```

Comment: This code is difficult to read and wrong. If the first expression is false (the one with strpos), the second will never be executed (short circuit evaluation). The result of strpos is an int or false, to test on false you should use `strpos() === false`, because the position 0 will also be considered false.

Comment: This will say that "0XAE" is a numeric integer, which may correct since it can evaluate to an int, but it's probably wrong for the question. It will also, incorrectly, say that "3e-1" is an int, when it will in fact evaluate to the float `0.3`